# Running Python inside Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, rest

I think I have a setting issue for Visual Studio... But a script that works just fine in Python IDLE 3.6 and in a separate anaconda IPython application (which I am used too) but does not run properly in VS 2017.

The script uses a package called pyhaystack to get data off of a building automation system (and build pandas df) and the packages installed just fine... Could there be setting in VS to make it run? Ultimately I am hoping to create a Django app in VS to show the API data thru HTML/web browser...

The code just runs forever in Visual Studio debug mode (f5) and the only thing I see in the output is this:

```
The thread 'MainThread' (0x2ec4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[11104] python.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

This is the Python script I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyhaystack.client.niagara import NiagaraHaystackSession


session = NiagaraHaystackSession(uri='http://1.1.1.1', username='@', password='!', pint=True)

rng = '2018-05-08,2018-05-09'

#Get Data for ProblemZnt
znt = session.find_entity(filter_expr='sensor and zone and temp and problem').result
znt = session.his_read_frame(znt, rng= rng).result
znt = pd.Series(znt[znt.columns[0]])

#Get Data for oat
oat = session.find_entity(filter_expr='sensor and outside and temp and air').result
oat = session.his_read_frame(oat, rng= rng).result
oat = pd.Series(oat[oat.columns[0]])


McheLrn = pd.DataFrame({'znt' : znt, 'oat' : oat})
McheLrn.index.names=['Date']
McheLrn.reset_index()

print(McheLrn)
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see? what do you get when you run it directly from idle?

Comment: The script works just fine in IDLE and IPython to make a request and build a pandas df, but it doesnt work when I run it in Visual Studio

Comment: Is Visual Studio more used for web development when using it for Python development or creating C++ wrapper? There seems to be some cool bells & whistles for Django but I wondering if it is not intended for API/datascience work..